# Extract weight and multiple in SSRS-2012

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

This is my query:

```
SELECT [Data] from usrrpt.Expansion EX WHERE EX.Order_PK = '231503796' AND EX.FieldName_PK like 'SHIPCOMMENT%'
```

and the data returned is as follows:

Data:

```
5 PLTS(STC: 20 CTNS)DIM:80X71X155CM@122KG

80X71X120CM@95KG X2, 80X71X120CM@96KG X4, 80X71X107CM@76KG

80X71X109CM@86KG X 7
```

How do I get the sum of the weight (`122 + 95 * 2 + 96 * 4 + 76 + 86 * 7`)?

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to do in SQL rather than in SSRS. It's perfectly possible to do in SSRS but the expressions would get messy. It's usually good practice to do the data side of things on the server and only the presentation done in the report where possible.

This is how I did it.

It relies on the following assumptions.

1. The weight is always between the first '@' and the next 'KG'
2. The multiplier is always after the weight and is preceded by an X
3. If no 'X' is found after the 'KG' then the multiplier is 1

The first things I did was recreate your data then I wrote a subquery to extract the weight and multiplier values as numeric, then wrapped this in another query that does a simple calculation to demonstrate that we have usable data to work with.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE([Data] varchar(1000))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('5 PLTS(STC: 20 CTNS)DIM:80X71X155CM@122KG'),
('80X71X120CM@95KG X2'),
('80X71X120CM@96KG X4'),
('80X71X107CM@76KG'),
('80X71X109CM@86KG X 7')

SELECT *, WeightKG * Multi as TotalWeight
FROM (
SELECT 
    *
    , WeightKG = CAST(SUBSTRING(
                            [Data] , 
                            CHARINDEX('@', [Data]) +1 ,  
                            CHARINDEX('KG', [Data], CHARINDEX('@', [Data])) - CHARINDEX('@', [Data]) - 1 
                            )
                        as Float)
    , Multi = CAST(
                        CASE CHARINDEX('X', [Data], CHARINDEX('KG', [Data]))
                            WHEN 0 THEN 1 
                            ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(
                                            SUBSTRING(
                                                [Data] , 
                                                CHARINDEX('X', [Data], CHARINDEX('KG', [Data])) + 1, 
                                                LEN([Data]) - CHARINDEX('X', [Data], CHARINDEX('KG', [Data])) + 1
                                                )
                                            ))
                        END
                        AS Float)

 FROM @t
) x
```

If you run this query, you will get the following results.

[image]